# How to indent AppleScript oneliner

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript oneliner that I would like to indent. But I wonder how to do this.

Here is the oneliner:

`tell application "System Events" to tell appearance preferences to set dark mode to not dark mode`

Here is how I tried to accomplish it:

```
tell application "System Events" to 
    tell appearance preferences to 
        set dark mode to not dark mode
    end tell
end tell
```

Apperently this won't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to keep your command as a "one-liner", but divide it over more than one line, then you need to make use of a line continuation character, which, in AppleScript, is denoted by `¬`.  This can be entered in *Script Editor* either by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, or by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Then you can split your one-liner like so:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell appearance preferences to ¬
        set dark mode to not dark mode
```

You can experiment with placing the line continuation character in different positions to achieve different types of indentation, e.g.:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
    appearance preferences to set ¬
    dark mode to not dark mode
```

If you want to change your one-liner (referred to as a *simple* `tell` command) to what is called a *compound* `tell` command—one that ends with `end tell`—then you should omit the `to` after each `tell` you wish to compound:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell appearance preferences
        set dark mode to not dark mode
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I've always used **⌥L** and didn't know about **⌥Enter**, nice answer! +1